# I have question about an example code in Microsoft Docs "FREETEXT (Transact SQL)"

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search, freetext

I want to use Freetext statement for search a phrase in SQL Server 2016 not separated words base on this sample code in Microsoft Docs.(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/freetext-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

```
USE AdventureWorks2012;  
GO  

DECLARE @SearchWord NVARCHAR(30);  
SET @SearchWord = N'high-performance';  

SELECT Description   
FROM Production.ProductDescription   
WHERE FREETEXT(Description, @SearchWord);  
GO
```

Is it a definition for using "-" in freetext?
Looks there is no difference between "high performance" and "high-performance" in results.

Comment: The feature is called **Full Text Search** (not "Free Text Search") - and yes, there will be no difference between your two search term, because FTS is **word-based**, it doesn't search and respond to whitespace and punctuation differences - it looks at the **words** in the search term - and those are identical